# Can´t add data through Java application to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, phpmyadmin

I have a crazy problem :D I have a Java application with a `Jtable` and the show, add, delete and update Buttons. The connection to my database works.

Now when I insert Data into my `Textfields` and click on submit (add) I can see the entry in my `Jtable`, but I cant see it in my Database.

This is crazy because I already have data in my Database some simple entries and my `JTable` is showing the data but when I insert data through the java app I can´t see the entry in my `phpmyadmin database` to which I am connected..

It´s hard to explain but maybe you can find the problem :/

**TABLE VIEW FROM JAVA JTABLE** https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAu7Y.jpg

**TABLE VIEW FROM PHPMYADMIN.COM** https://i.stack.imgur.com/68AvC.jpg

**MY CODE**

**CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
public void controllActionListenerAddEquipmentSubmitBtn(){
            main.setActionListenerAddEquipmentSubmitBtn(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if(arg0.getSource()==main.getButtonAddEquipmentBtn()){
                        EquipmentDAO edao = new EquipmentDAO();
                        try {
                                edao.create(main.addEquipmentSubmit());
                            } catch (SQLException e) {    
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

**MAINFRAME CLASS...(MAIN)**

```
 public Equipment addEquipmentSubmit(){
        equipment = new Equipment();
        equipment.setName(addEquipment.getName());
        equipment.setSection(addEquipment.getSection());
        equipment.setType(addEquipment.getType());
        equipment.setValue(Double.parseDouble((addEquipment.getValue())));
        equipment.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(addEquipment.getAmount()));
        return equipment;    
    }
```

**DAOCLASS**

```
package DAOCollection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import notesDBMySQL.DatabaseHandler;
import EntityClasses.Equipment;

public class EquipmentDAO implements DaoInterface{

    private Connection con;
    private java.sql.PreparedStatement sta;
    private Statement std;
    private ResultSet res;
    private DatabaseHandler handle;
    private String query;

    @Override
    public ResultSet show() throws SQLException{    
        handle = new DatabaseHandler();
        Connection con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
        String query = "select EID as ID, EquipmentName as Name, EquipmentSection as Section, EquipmentType as Type, EquipmentValue as Value, EquipmentAmount as Amount from Equipment";
        sta = con.prepareStatement(query);
        res = sta.executeQuery(query);
        return res;    
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Object c) throws SQLException {    
        handle = new DatabaseHandler();
        con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
        std = con.createStatement();
        Equipment equ = (Equipment) c ;
        query = "INSERT INTO Equipment(EquipmentName,EquipmentSection,EquipmentType,EquipmentValue, EquipmentAmount)"+"VALUES('"+equ.getName()+"','"+equ.getSection()+"','"+equ.getType()+"','"+equ.getValue()+"','"+equ.getAmount()+"')";
        std.execute(query);
        con.commit();
        handle.closeConnection();      
    }

    @Override    
    public void update(Object c) throws SQLException {    
        Equipment equ = (Equipment) c;
        handle = new DatabaseHandler();
        con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
        query = "UPDATE Equipment SET  name=?,section=?,type=?,value=?,amount=?,"+"WHERE EID=?";
        sta = con.prepareStatement(query);
        sta.setString(1, equ.getName());
        sta.setString(2,equ.getSection());
        sta.setString(3, equ.getType());
        sta.setDouble(4, equ.getValue());
        sta.setInt(5, equ.getAmount());
        sta.setInt(6, equ.getEid());
        sta.executeUpdate();
        sta.close();
        con.close();
        handle.closeConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) throws SQLException {    
        handle = new DatabaseHandler();
        con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
        query = "DELETE FROM EQUIPMENT"+"WHERE EID="+id;
        sta.executeUpdate(query);
        sta.close();
        con.close();
        handle.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

**ENTITY CLASS**

```
package EntityClasses;

public class Equipment {

    private int eid;
    private String name;
    private String section;
    private String type;
    private double value;
    private int amount;

    public int getEid() {
        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


}
```

**ADD CLASS**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    

public class AddEquipment extends JPanel {
    private JTextField txtu2;
    private JTextField txtu3;
    private JTextField txtu4;
    private JTextField txtu5;
    private JTextField txtu6;

    private JButton btnu8;
    private JButton btnu9; //Back Button

    public AddEquipment() {
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblu8 = new JLabel("Add Equipment");
        lblu8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblu8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblu8.setBounds(12, 13, 319, 33);
        add(lblu8);

        JLabel lblu3 = new JLabel("Name");
        lblu3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblu3.setBounds(60, 91, 46, 14);
        add(lblu3);

        txtu2 = new JTextField();
        txtu2.setColumns(10);
        txtu2.setBounds(221, 88, 377, 22);
        add(txtu2);

        JLabel lblu4 = new JLabel("Section");
        lblu4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblu4.setBounds(60, 156, 69, 14);
        add(lblu4);

        txtu3 = new JTextField();
        txtu3.setColumns(10);
        txtu3.setBounds(221, 153, 377, 22);
        add(txtu3);

        JLabel lblu5 = new JLabel("Type");
        lblu5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblu5.setBounds(60, 221, 46, 14);
        add(lblu5);

        txtu4 = new JTextField();
        txtu4.setColumns(10);
        txtu4.setBounds(221, 218, 377, 22);
        add(txtu4);

        JLabel lblu6 = new JLabel("Value");
        lblu6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblu6.setBounds(60, 286, 46, 14);
        add(lblu6);

        txtu5 = new JTextField();
        txtu5.setColumns(10);
        txtu5.setBounds(221, 283, 377, 22);
        add(txtu5);

        JLabel lblu7 = new JLabel("Amount");
        lblu7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblu7.setBounds(60, 351, 69, 14);
        add(lblu7);

        txtu6 = new JTextField();
        txtu6.setColumns(10);
        txtu6.setBounds(221, 348, 377, 22);
        add(txtu6);

        btnu8 = new JButton("Submit");
        btnu8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));

        //btnu8.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // button color
        //btnu8.setBackground( new Color(0, 0, 0, 50) ); //opacity

        btnu8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        btnu8.setBounds(422, 534, 110, 30);
        add(btnu8);

        btnu9 = new JButton("Back");
        btnu9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnu9.setBounds(542, 534, 110, 30);
        add(btnu9);

        JLabel lblback3 = new JLabel("");
        lblback3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("\\\\I-INTRA-03\\IIS-Lehre\\DAPRO-WF4.informatik.hs-ulm.de\\15\\group_together\\GUI_graphics\\background_panel.jpg"));
        lblback3.setBounds(0, 0, 664, 577);
        add(lblback3);  
    }

    //Getter-Method for the Back Button "btnu9"
    public JButton getBackAddEquipment(){
        return btnu9;   
    }

    //Getter-Method for the "Submit" Button "btnu8"
    public JButton getAddEquipmentBtn(){
            return btnu8;   
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.txtu2.getText();
    }

    // method sets the string value of the textfield
    public void setName(String txtu2) {
        this.txtu2.setText(txtu2);
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return this.txtu3.getText();
    }

    public void setSection(String txtu3) {
        this.txtu3.setText(txtu3);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.txtu4.getText();
    }

    public void setType(String txtu4) {
        this.txtu4.setText(txtu4);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.txtu5.getText();

    }

    public void setValue(String txtu5) {
        this.txtu5.setText(txtu5);
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return this.txtu6.getText();
    }

    public void setAmount(String txtu6) {
        this.txtu6.setText(txtu6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DAO implementation is asking for trouble.  You should never, ever return a `ResultSet`.  A better idea is to load the data into an object or data structure and close the `ResultSet` in method scope in a finally block.  Same for all your database resources.

Comment: first of all thx for your comment... you know a friend of mine has the same code .. really .. I mean i don´t understand what the problem is. and yes you are right with the resultset but he have the same code and his programm is adding the data to the database :/ and mine just into my jtable and not to my real database (look on phpmyadmin) @duffymo

Comment: You and your friend are both wrong, then.  I'd wonder if you have the proper permissions from your client IP address.  Check with your MySQL admit.  Your friend might have been GRANTed permission but you were not.

Comment: thank you we both changed it... instead of an resultset we now use an arraylist and safe the data in an object with a loop and then pass it :)